# How to pass arguments to a function that renders image crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

```
//inside admin controller    
public function pictures($table)
{ 
    $image = new image_CRUD();
    $image  ->  set_table($table)
            ->  set_url_field('name')
            ->  set_title_field('title')
            //->  set_ordering_field('priority')
            ->  set_image_path('assets/uploads');
    $output = $image -> render();            
    $this->view_output('images/main.php',$image -> render());
}
```

url: `localhost/my_site/admin/pictures/photos` and I get a bunch of errors for undefined variable of css_files and js_files and invalid argument for foreach(). when url is `localhost/my_site/admin/pictures` and the code is as below, it works perfect.

```
//inside admin controller    
public function pictures()
{ 
    $image = new image_CRUD();
    $image  ->  set_table('photos')
            ->  set_url_field('name')
            ->  set_title_field('title')
            //->  set_ordering_field('priority')
            ->  set_image_path('assets/uploads');
    $output = $image -> render();            
    $this->view_output('images/main.php',$image -> render());
}
```

The problem is while using codeigniter's method of passing arguments on image crud rendering function. While using normal method of php as `http://localhost/my_site/admin/pictures?table=photos` and the code is as below, it works, BUT I can't upload images this way,there will be upload error.

```
public function pictures()
{        
        $image = new image_CRUD();
        $table = $_GET['table'];
        $image  ->  set_table($table)
        ......
}
```

How can I pass arguments as I stated first?

OK I got the solution. Previously the library `image_crud.php` getState() function did not have the condition for uri segment being other than  numberic,'upload_file', 'ajax_list', 'ordering' and 'insert_title'. So the error was due to not finding the suitable condition and code didn't execute. Below given code must be added to the library:`image_crud.php` line 477:

```
else
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/upload_file');
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;

            return (object)$state;
        }
```

**Okay this way has got a error while uploading files.**

Previously while uploading files (while we dont have 3rd uri segment), it adds extra segments on the 3rd uri to define the state of the image_crud. I modified it to work while having 3rd uri segment.So in this case, I have a two conditions. First while having third uri segment and second, not having third uri segment. So $extra_segments variable is set to false( false for no extra segments,i.e localhost/my_site/admin/pictures in my case) while we don't have 3rd uri segment. For checking 3rd uri segment, the function `set_table` of `image_crud.php`is modified as:

```
function set_table($table_name)
{
    $this->table_name = $table_name;

    if($table_name == $this->ci->uri->segment(3))
    {
        $this->extra_segments = true;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

also variable is to be declared inside image_crud class(on line 47 I did) as:
`protected $extra_segments = false;`
Now for actual work, getState() function is modified as below. It can be furthur optimised to make it dry and modular.

```
protected function getState()
{
    $rsegments_array = $this->ci->uri->rsegment_array();

    if($this->extra_segments == true){

        if(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && is_numeric($rsegments_array[4]))
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/upload_file/'.$rsegments_array[3]);
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url, 'relation_value' => $rsegments_array[4]);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[5]) && $rsegments_array[5] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;


            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif( (empty($rsegments_array[4]) && empty($this->relation_field)) || (!empty($rsegments_array[4]) &&  $rsegments_array[4] == 'ajax_list'))
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/upload_file');
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;

            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'upload_file')
        {
            #region Just rename my file
                $new_file_name = '';
                //$old_file_name = $this->_to_greeklish($_GET['qqfile']);
                $old_file_name = $this->_convert_foreign_characters($_GET['qqfile']);
                $max = strlen($old_file_name);
                for($i=0; $i< $max;$i++)
                {
                    $numMatches = preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.-_]+$/', $old_file_name[$i], $matches);
                    if($numMatches >0)
                    {
                        $new_file_name .= strtolower($old_file_name[$i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $new_file_name .= '-';
                    }
                }
                $file_name = substr( substr( uniqid(), 9,13).'-'.$new_file_name , 0, 100) ;
            #endregion

            $results = array( 'name' => 'upload_file', 'file_name' => $file_name);
            if(isset($rsegments_array[5]) && is_numeric($rsegments_array[5]))
            {
                $results['relation_value'] = $rsegments_array[5];
            }
            return (object)$results;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && isset($rsegments_array[5]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'delete_file' && is_numeric($rsegments_array[5]))
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'delete_file', 'id' => $rsegments_array[4]);
            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'ordering')
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'ordering');
            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'insert_title')
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'insert_title');
            return (object)$state;
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/upload_file');
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;

            return (object)$state;
        }
     }
    elseif($this->extra_segments == false)
    {
        if(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && is_numeric($rsegments_array[3]))
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/upload_file/'.$rsegments_array[3]);
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url, 'relation_value' => $rsegments_array[3]);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;


            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif( (empty($rsegments_array[3]) && empty($this->relation_field)) || (!empty($rsegments_array[3]) &&  $rsegments_array[3] == 'ajax_list'))
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/upload_file');
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;

            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'upload_file')
        {
            #region Just rename my file
                $new_file_name = '';
                //$old_file_name = $this->_to_greeklish($_GET['qqfile']);
                $old_file_name = $this->_convert_foreign_characters($_GET['qqfile']);
                $max = strlen($old_file_name);
                for($i=0; $i< $max;$i++)
                {
                    $numMatches = preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.-_]+$/', $old_file_name[$i], $matches);
                    if($numMatches >0)
                    {
                        $new_file_name .= strtolower($old_file_name[$i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $new_file_name .= '-';
                    }
                }
                $file_name = substr( substr( uniqid(), 9,13).'-'.$new_file_name , 0, 100) ;
            #endregion

            $results = array( 'name' => 'upload_file', 'file_name' => $file_name);
            if(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && is_numeric($rsegments_array[4]))
            {
                $results['relation_value'] = $rsegments_array[4];
            }
            return (object)$results;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'delete_file' && is_numeric($rsegments_array[4]))
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'delete_file', 'id' => $rsegments_array[4]);
            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'ordering')
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'ordering');
            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'insert_title')
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'insert_title');
            return (object)$state;
        }
    }
}
```

Also `url` helper must be autoloaded or loaded to uri checking function.

Comment: what kinda arguments you need to pass? and why not to pass it through post?!

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I need to pass a table-name to controller for accessing photos of different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with [url_helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

add a line in your controller's constructor

```
 $this->load->helper('url');

public function pictures()
{ 
    $table = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
    $image = new image_CRUD();
    $image  ->  set_table($table)
            ->  set_url_field('name')
            ->  set_title_field('title')
            //->  set_ordering_field('priority')
            ->  set_image_path('assets/uploads');
    $output = $image -> render();            
    $this->view_output('images/main.php',$image -> render());
}
```

Comment: and the problem is same. There is always an error while passing third segment in uri.

Comment: OK I got the solution.

Comment: @ry35xq28 it was not possible to guess the exact error after what you posted in question.